# Validate LinkedIn Company is exists or not using LinkedIn API

Tags: validation, linkedin-api

I want to validate LinkedIn Company is exists or not using LinkedIn API. I have used [this link](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1337?format=json)  But that shows
 `{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "JU7WN815MA",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1464156122597
}`

Note: I have created the app in [this link](https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/)
I got only Client ID and Client Secret.
I followed [this link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) too.

How to get access token, Secret Key and all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps outlined on the LinkedIn developer website to acquire an OAuth 2.0 access token that will then let you make the API call.

More details here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: Thanks @Justin. How can i get details using this link: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(companies:(id,name,logo_url))?keywords=keyword?oauth2_access_token={accesstoken}&format=json

Comment: Company Search is no longer an openly available API endpoint.  All of the functionality you have access to w/r/t Company Page management can be found here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages